# Canopy Scrapy TypeError

Tags: scrapy, enthought, canopy

I am trying to use scrapy inside Enthought Canopy Python distribution. I installed scrapy, but while trying to import, I get following TypeError

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
----> 1 import scrapy

C:\Users\ad\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\scrapy__init__.pyc in ()
      8 # Scrapy version
      9 import pkgutil
---> 10 **version** = pkgutil.get_data(**package**, 'VERSION').decode('ascii').strip()
     11 version_info = tuple(int(v) if v.isdigit() else v
     12                      for v in **version**.split('.'))

C:\Users\ad\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.4.1.1975.win-x86_64\lib\pkgutil.pyc in get_data(package, resource)
    576     """
    577 
--> 578     loader = get_loader(package)
    579     if loader is None or not hasattr(loader, 'get_data'):
    580         return None

C:\Users\ad\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.4.1.1975.win-x86_64\lib\pkgutil.pyc in get_loader(module_or_name)
    462     else:
    463         fullname = module_or_name
--> 464     return find_loader(fullname)
    465 
    466 def find_loader(fullname):

C:\Users\ad\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.4.1.1975.win-x86_64\lib\pkgutil.pyc in find_loader(fullname)
    473     """
    474     for importer in iter_importers(fullname):
--> 475         loader = importer.find_module(fullname)
    476         if loader is not None:
    477             return loader

TypeError: find_module() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)

## Any thoughts?

edit: Uninstalling older version and installing newer version worked.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly how did you install scrapy? It has many dependencies which are not included in the Canopy installation. If you are a subscriber (paid or free academic), you can use the Canopy Package Manager or `enpkg` command line utility to install the pre-built scrapy from the Canopy repository; this takes care of all dependencies. (Just tested on Canopy 1.5.1 -- it's also possible that there's a problem doing this in Canopy 1.4.1, the version that you are running. In that case, and anyway to get many improvements, you might want to uninstall 1.4.1, download 1.5.1 from https://enthought.com/downloads and install it. It would be cleanest to start with a fresh set of packages, by deleting the User Python directory before restarting Canopy (this is the one that is pointed to by typing `sys.prefix` in the Canopy IPython pane.)